# Add p around text inside contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

Using the code below, I can successfully enter text inside a `contenteditable` div  and rather than creating a new `div` when the enter button is pressed, it creates `<br>`.

How would I add `<p>` tags around the text inside the `contentedtiable` div?

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('pre').text($('div')[0].outerHTML)
});

$('div[contenteditable=true]').keydown(function(e) {
  // trap the return key being pressed
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // insert 2 br tags (if only one br tag is inserted the cursor won't go to the second line)
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');
    // prevent the default behaviour of return key pressed
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 50px; border: 1px solid;" contenteditable="true"></div>
<pre></pre>
<button>Show Source</button>
```

My desired output from the script above would be as follows:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>
  // content here
  </p>
</div>
```

*Note: I do not want the `<p>` tags to be added on a button click, but rather happen automatically.*

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r3qthx6d/5/

**UPDATE**

Using `$('div[contenteditable=true]').wrapInner('<p></p>');` adds `<p>` tags at the end of the text when something is typed inside the `contenteditable` div as demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/r3qthx6d/3/

This is not what I need though, as my aim is to have the content **surrounded** by the `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('div[contenteditable=true]').wrapInner('<p></p>');
```

Comment: THIS ANSWER DOES NOT SOLVE MY PROBLEM. It doesn't add `<p>` tags around text when it's typed: jsfiddle.net/r3qthx6d/3

Comment: You need to wrap text in the p tag after he pressed enter?

Comment: I had thought about that, but they may only type in one line of text. Your code seems to put the text before the `<p>` tags

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

`document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');`

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jfb35opu/